What primer should I use on varnished door?
I am looking to paint these doors and my original plan was as follows:

Lightly sand the door
Wipe it down with M1 deglosser (maybe I can skip this step since i sanded it down)
Apply Sherwin Williams Multi-Purpose primer (https://www.sherwin-williams.com/homeowners/products/multipurpose-interiorexterior-latex-primersealer)
Then paint with Sherwin William Emerald Urethane trim paint (https://www.sherwin-williams.com/homeowners/products/emerald-urethane-trim-enamel)

However after some research, I am wondering I should use bonding primer. I have some Bin Shellac Primer (red) on hand which I was thinking to use. Also it looks like people had great success with Benjamin Moore Stix. SW also has their Extreme bond primer.
SW employees said if I am sanding down the door, I can just use their multi-purpose primer that I was going to use on some dark colored walls. Not sure If I should take their word.
Below are the doors and trims I am trying to paint:



When you say "lightly sand," do you mean take it back to bare wood or just add some roughness to help the primer adhere?

Why would you take our word if not product specialists? The only way you'll really know is to try it and do a scratch test. Note that product recommendations are off topic here. See the [help] and take the [tour].

@AndrewMorton yeah to add some roughness to help the primer to adhere. I am not sure if I should use bonding primer or the multi-purpose primer should work.

@isherwood I read lots of review where it said the SW store employees steered people in wrong direction. Understood that i will not know until i try it out but I am just trying get some tips from people who either used same type primer or recommend different type.

Painting a nice wood door is a shame, if not a sacrilege... But if you're determined to do so, clean the surface thoroughly with something like tri-sodium phosphate (TSP) to de-grease it, possibly lightly sand, apply a shellac-based universal primer (or just shellac) to ensure whatever you paint it with will adhere, then use whatever primer and paint you like as long as those are compatible with each other (both must be oil-based, both must be water-based, or you need another shellac layer to interface between them).
